# Selenium error: ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium robot that downloads two CSV files on a website. First, he does download a CSV, waits to finish and start the download process of the second CSV.

However, they are unable to complete the download of the second CSV and the following error appears:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 725, in urlopen
  File "site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 403, in increment
  File "site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
  File "site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 426, in _make_request
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1344, in getresponse
  File "http/client.py", line 306, in begin
  File "http/client.py", line 267, in _read_status
  File "socket.py", line 589, in readinto
  File "ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
  File "ssl.py", line 929, in read
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 870, in run
  File "compose/cli/log_printer.py", line 169, in tail_container_logs
  File "compose/cli/log_printer.py", line 200, in wait_on_exit
  File "compose/container.py", line 281, in wait
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
  File "site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 1289, in wait
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 226, in _post
  File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 581, in post
  File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
  File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
  File "site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Any idea what might be going on?

The project is in the docker and I am using versions:

```
    Python 3.6

    chromedriver --version
    ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 
    
    
    google-chrome --version
    Google Chrome 83.0.4103.116
```